# parse xml and create excel sheets for xml data using python

Tags: python, openpyxl, elementtree

getting input file as a xml data containing items like id,name,productnr

eg:-

```
enter code here

         <ID>1001</ID>
         <PRODUCTNR>21</PRODUCTNR>
         <NAME>XYZ</NAME>
    </itemlist>
    
    <itemlist>
         <ID>1002</ID>
         <PRODUCTNR>22</PRODUCTNR>
         <NAME>abc</NAME>
    </itemlist>
```

.So need to parse xml file and create excel sheets like column should be id,name,productnr and these column contain data in row.All this done in python. using modules like xml.etree.elementtree and from openpyxl import workbook.

i want a proper python code that provide me appropriate output using modules which i have written

Comment: Try using [`pd.read_xml`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html) and [`to_excel()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html).

Comment: "i want a proper python code..." - What have you tried so far? What is the problem?

Comment: You may want to read [ask]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Fisrt, install the [openpyxl](https://pypi.org/project/openpyxl/) library

```
`import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
 from openpyxl import Workbook`
```

`

```
 def parse_xml_to_excel(xml_file, excel_file):
    tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
    root = tree.getroot()

    wb = Workbook()
    ws = wb.active

    # Write header to Excel
    ws.append(["ID", "NAME", "PRODUCTNR"])

    # Parse XML and write data to Excel
    for itemlist in root:
        id_val = itemlist.find("ID").text
        name_val = itemlist.find("NAME").text
        productnr_val = itemlist.find("PRODUCTNR").text
        ws.append([id_val, name_val, productnr_val])

    wb.save(excel_file)
    print(f"Excel file '{excel_file}' has been created successfully.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    xml_file = "input.xml"
    excel_file = "output.xlsx"
    parse_xml_to_excel(xml_file, excel_file)
```

`

in the code above replace "input.xml" with the path to your input XML file, and "output.xlsx" with the desired name for the Excel file.